# Search result conditonal tag

Tags: search, conditional-content

Is there a conditional tag (or a similar concept) that can tell me wether the search returned posts or not?

Answer (score 1):

```
global $wp_query;
echo $wp_query->found_posts;
```

Comment: Or `if( have_posts() )` should pretty much do the same, ie. tell you if there are more than 0 posts returned in the query.